# dynamic Select statement on declared table variable - SYBASE

Tags: select, dynamic, sybase, table-variable

I have one declared table variable in stored procedure,(sybase database). Data is populated in that table as needed. But now I want to select particular columns based on different conditions. I am trying dynamic SQL to do the same but not working. Can it go like I am assuming?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "dbo"."sp_userMenus" 
@fundName VARCHAR(20) , @userName VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
declare @tableData as table (
        id int IDENTITY(1,1),
        [menuDisplayName] nvarchar(100),
        [menuOrder] int,
        [menuType] nvarchar(100),
        [parentVerticalMenu] nvarchar(100),
        [parentHorizontalMenu] nvarchar(100),
        [groupID] int,
        [inDashboardAll] int,
        [inDashboardOverview] int,
        [inDetail] int,
        [inSummary] int,
        [isDetail] int,
        [zOrder] int
    )

    --insert into @tableData

    if @userName = 'ADMIN'
        SET @SQLQuery = 'select *
            from @tableData order by parentVerticalMenu, parentHorizontalMenu'
    else
        SET @SQLQuery = 'select menuDisplayName,menuOrder,menuType,parentVerticalMenu,parentHorizontalMenu 
            from @tableData order by parentVerticalMenu, parentHorizontalMenu'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

END
```

**getting error "Must declare the scalar variable "@tableData" OR Must declare the table variable "@tableData".**

Answer (score 1):

Change the code:

```
declare @tableData as table (
```

To:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableData (
```

Change the references from `@tableData` to `#tableData`

The temporary table will exist until the current session or procedure ends, or until its you drop it using drop table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the keyword 'as' prior to 'table'